# Refining Disparity maps?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

Can anyone tell me of a method to refine disparity maps? I am trying to generate the disparity map of a face but the features like eyes, nose ,lips etc are not clear.How can I refine it to make it look better?

Comment: I think you'll have to define better what is wrong with your disparity map before we can help you.  Can you post an image or two - maybe "tart them up" by hand to show what you'd like as an output?  Tell us more about how you are producing your disparity map and what your end goal is for the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 
https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/stereo_match.cpp
there are some bm.state parameters (about line 197 - 207) that can be tweaked, we connected those values to some sliders so we could look at the result at the same time as we tweaked the values. you can also try with some different values for "blocksize". you can also try with some different distances between your cameras, if the cameras are too far apart, you will get poor / no results on close distances.

I assume that your code is similar to the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Use stereoSGBM I am using it and you can use trackbars to tweak the parameters study the refernece of opencv and then manipulate each parameter based on the effect it has on your image eg:P1 P2 make it smoother etc